# AIS SOG: Handling Negative Values

Tags: python, data-preprocessing, ais

I'm working with an AIS dataset. The SOG (speed over ground) field has negative values, but the supported values are between 0 and 102.2 knots. How should I handle these values?

[image: df.describe() of the dataset]

Comment: This sounds like a question about the AIS data itself and is only tangentially related to programming. You might want to consider asking this question on https://gis.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Can you post the corresponding NMEA sentence?

Comment: @tbsalling I only have the data in CSV format (https://doi.org/10.15480/336.4471). The original data source is https://marinecadastre.gov/ais/.

Comment: @afonsomm ah ok. It's just that if you had the original message I could manually decode it for you. Sometimes negative numbers (and other strange) numbers have a special meaning in AIS.